# SQL Computed column based on another computed column

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a computed column in one of my database to determine if a product is under cost...

I have the following column:

```
[Cost],[Price] money
[Profit]=[Price]-[Cost]
```

And I want to have a computed column which should look like that:

```
[UnderCost]=([Profit]<0)
```

Comment: just use `([Price]-[Cost])<0`

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your question is not at all clear. But you can't use a computed column as the value for another computed column. Any computed column needs to have the full calculation in it.

Comment: @JamieD77 that won't work. There is no such thing as a boolean in t-sql. You could use a case expression though.

Comment: I Tried: CASE WHEN ([Profit]<0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

Comment: Use your case expression but you can't use another computed column, put the calculation in there.

Comment: oops.. `IIF(([Price]-[Cost])<0,1,0)`?